# MySQL is not running into WAMP

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I've just start learning SQL.
I download MySql and after them download WAMP Server.

But MySQL doesnt appear into my WAMP package. How can I include?

Comment: WAMP has a mysql server of it's own, so if you have downloaded and installed mysql separately, probably it's already serving on port 3306 and preventing the mysql server in wamp to be started

Comment: By "WAMP Server" do you mean [WampServer](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/)?  What do you mean by "doesn't appear into"?

Comment: Yes, WampServer. First I downloaded MySQL Workbench. After that, I Downloaded WampServer. By that time, I didn't know that I just had to dowload Wamp. The problem is: I can't connect MySQL with WampServer.

Comment: Because Workbench is a bit useless without a database to play with, it also downloads MySQL. So you almost definitely have 2 MySQL Server instances on your system. If you have databases you wish to keep, back them up, then uninstall Workbench (and its MySQL) then check WAMPServer, its MySQL shoudl now be starting. If so restore the backed up database(s). Then reinstall WorkBench, but without its own MySQL

Answer (score 1):

I have experience with xampp but I think it's the same thing they come with built-in MySQL and Apache and other things so you only need to install wamp at least that's what it takes for xampp